# Sum on interest

Tags: meaning, grammar

What is the meaning of this statement?

> She shall receive 5% interest for each year on the sum of $100,000 for 10 years.

Does it mean that she has to get $100,000 (it say ON the SUM) plus interest for 10 years or she has to get just interest for ten years? I suggest that it should be FROM the SUM if she have to get just interest.

Comment: It's an archaic "legalese" use of ***on*** rather than ***from***. She'll receive £5000 each year for 10 years, but nothing is said here about where the capital sum of £100,000 comes from (perhaps *she herself* has to put up the money), or what happens to it afterwards.

Comment: _sum_ just means _amount_, it doesn't refer to adding things.

Comment: 5% p/a interest? WHERE?

Comment: Should it be 5% isn't added or 5% aren't added?

Comment: 5% isn't added!!

Answer (score 1):

[Sum](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sum) does not refer to the operation of addition, but rather to "an indefinite or specified amount of money"; in this case, the specified amount is $100,000.

"Interest on (amount)", in a financial sense such as this, means a percentage of the amount to be paid at some interval; however, the original amount itself is not spent or paid out, so it does not diminish.  If you have $1000 in the bank and they pay you 5% interest on it, that means you get a $50 payment, AND you still have your $1000, so you now have a total of $1050.

So, the upshot of it is, somewhere there is $100,000.  "She" will receive $5,000 every year for 10 years, for a total of $50,000.  At the end of 10 years, the $100,000 will still be there.  (Presumably, anyway; other terms of the agreement may specify what happens to it.)

Answer (score 0):

We can, without changing the meaning, remove the term that's tripping you up:

> She shall receive 5% interest for each year on <strike>the sum of</strike> $100,000 for 10 years.

to give

> She shall receive 5% interest for each year on $100,000 for 10 years.

Further, it's usually assumed that interest is interest-per-annum, so we can remove that part too:

> She shall receive 5% interest on $100,000 for 10 years.

or restate it another way.

> She shall receive 5% interest on $100,000 for 10 years, compounded annually.

---

The phrasing hidden in the quote is "**interest [...] on the sum of $100,000**". I think they had to put the "for each year" part in where they did because it's the only place it fits logically; removing it makes the meaning a bit more clear.

Comment: It's not clear whether the interest is compounded, vs being simply paid to "she".

Comment: Actually it does. The interest is 5% of $100,000. If the interest is to be compounded, the sentence would add the phrase, "compounded annually (or biannually, or whatever)" at the end of the sentence. Since there is no mention of compounding, no compounding will take place.